# gitlab-runner running out of space, with added disk drive

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab-runner (docker executor) that is building a large docker image using `docker build`. This is running out of space.

To remedy this, I mounted an external disk (with adequate space) and created a partition. This can be found and accessed at `/run/media/<user>/STORAGE`. I created a directory here called `builds`, where I hope Gitlab-runner to build my docker images (using the new external disks space).

Under the `[[runners]]` settings in `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`, I have set `builds_dir = "/run/media/<user>/STORAGE/builds"`.

The gitlab-runner logs suggest that the external disk is being used (`Initialized empty Git repository in /run/media/<user>/STORAGE/builds/<user>/<repository-name>/.git/`), but the build is still failing at the same stage and time (`no space left on device`), suggesting that the build itself is still being done on the old disk space.

Have I understood the purpose of the `builds_dir` setting correctly? How do I get gitlab-runner to just use the new disk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by changing the docker data root directory (`/var/lib/docker` by default) to a folder on my external drive.

This was done by editing `/etc/docker/daemon.json` to include the following:

```
{ 
   "data-root": "/path/to/your/drive" 
}
```

I then had to restart docker.